# Turn of Google Calendar event sounds

Tags: samsung, audio, google-calendar

I recently upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy S23. I previously had all sounds off on all previous devices. I have checked this phone and no sounds are on anywhere on the phone. But every time I get a Google Calendar event notification, it plays a damn tune.

I cannot figure out how to turn this off! I have tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the app drawer, long press on the Calendar app.
2. App info > Manage notifications
3. At the bottom, you will see 2 categories

   - Calendar notifications
   - Task notifications

   Both have a button, but both buttons are grayed out because it is a system app.
4. Select which you wish to make silent
5. Select "Set as silent". This should work.

   [image]

Let me know if this works. Thanks!